# Checking if a string contains uppercase

Tags: string, haskell

I am new to Haskell and I can't seem to get my code written correctly.

I have tried :

```
identifier :: String -> String
identifier input
    | isUpper input == True = putStrLn("*** Exception: Uppercase" ++ input)
    | return input
```

And my latest try was:

```
identifier :: String -> String
identifier input = do
    if isUpper input == True
        then putStrLn("*** Exception : Uppercase" ++ input)
        else return input
```

It should return the exception message when the input contains a uppercase letter.
And return the input when it is lowercase or any other character.
Can someone maybe suggest a better way of writing this?

Comment: Style comment: there's no need to write `something == True`, since that is equivalent to simply `something`. It's also equivalent to `(something == True) == True`, but you wouldn't write that, would you? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to include "normal" input/output you have to make your function

```
identifier :: String -> IO String
```

otherwise (even if it is not a good habit to write unsafe functions) I recommend to use `error "*** Exception …"` (if you want to use real exceptions take a look at `Control.Except` and `MonadThrow/MonadCatch`.

next - I assume `isUpper` is imported from `Data.Char` and only works on characters. I would combine `isUpper` with the function `all` that checks if a property (here `isUpper`) is true for all elements of a list - which can be applied to a `String` as it is just a synonym for `[Char]`. I also recommend not checking for upper but lowercase as this is your goal.

so you can have something like

```
if (all isLower input)
  then input
  else error "i will promise to look at Data.Maybe and Data.Either in the near future"
```

Answer (score 3):

> It should return the exception message when the input contains a uppercase letter. And return the input when it is lowercase or any other character. Can someone maybe suggest a better way of writing this?

- Avoid functions that throw exceptions and produce side-effects when they can be written [purely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).
- `putStrLn ("*** Exception: ...")` will not produce an exception. `error "Uppercase"` will.

If your function has the signature `String -> String`, it cannot

- use `isUpper` on the input, since `Data.Char.isUpper :: Char -> Bool`, or
- use `putStrLn` as the output, since `System.IO.putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`.

If the only criterion for a valid identifier is that it doesn't contain uppercase latters, you could write:

```
isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
isIdentifier = not . any isUpper
```

although you probably want to formulate all criteria for valid identifiers as one predicate. That could for example be matching something like *[_a-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]+*:

```
isIdentifier :: String -> Bool
isIdentifier (c:cs) = (c == '_' || isLower c) && all (\c -> c == '_' || isAlphaNum c) cs
isIdentifier "" = False
```

Comment: I think your `identifier` function only checks the first letter of a `String` and no other - so it would not yield a correct result for "d'Artagnan". I think you should call `isIdentifier` recursively or use a `fold`